# Excluding Tomcat dependencies from Spring Boot in Gradle

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with Jetty and it seems I cannot exclude all the Tomcat dependencies in my Gradle build file.

Relevant part of build.gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter") {
    exclude module: "tomcat-embed-el"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

Yet when I run `gradle dependencies` parts of tomcat are still there, and causing issues with WebSockets:

```
...
|    
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.4.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final -> 3.3.0.Final
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.1.0 -> 1.3.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.3
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 -> 2.8.3
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.3
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.4.1.RELEASE
|         +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.5
|         +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.5
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.5
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.5
...
```

Why isn't `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` excluded from `spring-boot-starter-web` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Aha, found the reason.

I also had `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")` dependency that was also depending on `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`. Gradle dependency output mislead me into thinking that `spring-boot-starter-web` is the reason why Tomcat was still there.

I had to add the following:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

Lesson learned is that when you want to exclude something, double-check all of your dependencies to make sure it is excluded from all the places. And gradle dependencies output could be improved to make it less misleading...

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Kresimir Nesek, saved my day !!

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, so on top of excluding **spring-boot-starter-tomcat** I also had to exclude **tomcat-embed-*** jars, I did this through **gradle configurations**

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  compile.exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat'
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Undertow was working in Eclipse but not in the jar, adding this, made it work. For those using a newer gradle version, don't change compile to implementation. Use exactly like it is written here.

Answer (score 7):

Using Kotlin DSL, add in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
configurations {
    implementation.configure {
       exclude(module = "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
       exclude("org.apache.tomcat")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## gradle hack

With Gradle 6 this worked for me without the module exclusion mentioned above:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

## plugin config

The [spring boot gradle plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) 4.2.1 recommends to declare provided dependencies like this (assuming you build a war):

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

The dependencies won't be removed from the war but moved to a location where they usually don't harm.

```
WEB-INF/lib-provided/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar
WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar
WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.30.jar
```

Comment: This is just simple and very elegant solution. All tomcat related libs are moved to lib-provided folder inside WEB-INF and rest libs remained in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: The benefit of this solution is that you still have all deployment options. The war file can be installed in jetty AND you can still run the war in standalone mode executing java -jar myapp.war

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Krešimir Nesek is inspired me to solve my bug. But I solve it in a little different way.

My problem is invoked by including other module with Spring-Boot from a module built upon WebFlux and springCoroutines in Kotlin.

My way in Kotlin is :

```
 exclude("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

The first argument `"org.springframework.boot"` is for group, the second one is for specific module.

Answer (score 0):

The complete example of the dependency (Kotlin DSL):

```
implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-web") {
   exclude(module = "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Gradle 7.5.1

All I had to do was to add this to build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    exclude group: "org.apache.tomcat.embed", module: "tomcat-embed-el"
}
```

No need to use the `exclude` clause in the project dependencies. (If you're on IntelliJ, don't forget to load/reload the gradle changes.)