# How to generate non-executable war file for Reactive Spring Boot 2.0.0 application using Gradle?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, gradle, war

I created Spring Boot 2.0.0 Reactive Web Application. This is the entire build.gradle file

```
  buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group = 'myproj'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')

        runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
        compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

        testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
        }
```

it works fine running under eclipse IDE using embedded servlet container.

This is the code for main class:

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a requirement that I must deploy this Reactive Spring Boot app as war to Tomcat 8.5 because it depends on another traditional non-reactive war app running under same tomcat instance. Is this possible given above code and how?

This is Spring Boot 2.0.0 reactive web app and is different question from those that may look similar on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Excluding Tomcat dependencies from Spring Boot in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275516/excluding-tomcat-dependencies-from-spring-boot-in-gradle)

Comment: Not exact duplicate, that has starter-tomcat starter-jetty deps, I dont have those deps and my project has Spring Reactive deps which is quite different under tomcat.