# How to exclude dependencies in gradle 5.5.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I want to exclude a module in gradle `5.5.1`. But exclude does not work

I want to deploy spring boot in Tomcat7. So I choose to exclude embed tomcat in spring.
But I found that exclude does not work, like following scripts.

My Gradle Version is `5.5.1`

```
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.6.RELEASE') {
    force = true
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
 }
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.xxx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
ext['tomcat.version'] = '7.0.59'


dependencies {
version:property('tomcat.version')




compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.6.RELEASE') {
     force = true
      exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  }
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.59'
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.59'
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.59'
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat7-websocket:7.0.59'



    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

How to exclude dependencies in Gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding Tomcat dependencies from Spring Boot in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275516/excluding-tomcat-dependencies-from-spring-boot-in-gradle) may be try some of those

Comment: Post your gradle code if possible.

Comment: @Deadpool no, that was two years ago, I am using version 5.5.1

Comment: @Sambit I edited it right now

Comment: Did you check the duplicate so link, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this hasn't changed in recent Gradle versions and still works the same.